# C# XNA 2D trail effect optimization

Tags: c#, optimization, xna, 2d, sprite

Currently as a trail effect in my game I have for every 5 frames a translucent texture copy of a sprite is added to a List<> of trails.

The alpha values of these trails is decremented every frame and a draw function iterates through the list and draws each texture. Once they hit 0 alpha they are removed from the List<>.

The result is a nice little trail effect behind moving entities. The problem is for about 100+ entities, the frame rate begins to drop drastically.

All trail textures come from the same sprite sheet so i dont think it's batching issue. I profiled the code and the CPU intensity is lower during the FPS drop spikes then it is at normal FPS so I assume that means its a GPU limitation?

Is there any way to achieve this effect more efficiently?

Heres the general code im using:

```
// fade alpha
m_alpha -= (int)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 10.0f);

// draw
if (m_alpha > 0) {
    // p is used to alter RGB of the trails color (m_tint) depending on alpha value
    float p = (float)m_alpha/255.0f;
    Color blend = new Color((int)(m_tint.R*p), (int)(m_tint.G*p), (int)(m_tint.B*p), m_alpha);               
    // draw texture to sprite batch
    Globals.spriteBatch.Draw(m_texture, getOrigin(), m_rectangle, blend, getAngle(), new Vector2(m_rectangle.Width/2, m_rectangle.Height/2), m_scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);                
} else {
        // flag to remove from List<>
        m_isDone = true;               
}
```

I guess i should note, the m_texture given to the trail class is a reference to a global texture shared by all trails. Im note creating a hard copy for each trail.

EDIT: If I simply comment out the SpriteBatch.Draw call, even when im allocating a new trail every single frame for hundreds of objects there is no drop in frames... there has got to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Have to tried disabling/removing the trail effect to ensure it's the cause?

Comment: yeah removing the trail effect completely fixes the frame rate drop. I figure the trails is just adding too many sprites for the GPU to handle...

Comment: You should post some code. Clearly such a thing is possible, particle systems easily accomplish more than 100 particles all fading away.

Comment: How large is the source rectangle for the particles?

Comment: Are you honestly making a copy of the texture every 5 frames? if that's true stop doing that and just draw the same texture at different alpha values.

Comment: As Scott W said. Don't remove them from the list, just alter the alpha value then set them back to default as needed. What you are currently doing is slow as you are deallocating then reallocating constantly. The GPU can handle more than a few trails, would be surprised if it couldn't...

Comment: Source rectangles range from 100x100 to 300x300 pixels. All trails reference the same static Texture2D object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually for trails, instead of clearing the screen on every frame, you simply draw a transparent screen-sized rectangle before drawing the current frame.  Thus the previous frame is "dimmed" or "color blurred" while the newer frame is fully "clear" and "bright".  As this is repeated, a trail is generated from all the previous frames, which are never cleared but rather "dimmed".

This technique is VERY efficient and it is used in the famous Flurry screensaver (www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKPEivA8x4g).

In order to make the trails longer, you simply increase the transparency of the rectangle that you use to clear the screen.  Otherwise, you make it more opaque to make the trail shorter.  Note, however, that if you make the trails too long by making the rectangle too transparent, you risk leaving some light traces of the trail that due to alpha blending, might not completely erase even after a long time.  The Flurry screensaver suffers from this kind of artifact, but there are ways to compensate for it.

Depending on your situation, you might have to adapt the technique.  For instance, you might want to have several drawing layers that allow certain objects to leave a trail while others don't generate trails.

This technique is more efficient for long trails than trying to redraw a sprite thousands of times as your current approach.

On the other hand, I think the bottleneck in your code is the following line:

```
Globals.spriteBatch.Draw(m_texture, getOrigin(), m_rectangle, blend, getAngle(), new Vector2(m_rectangle.Width/2, m_rectangle.Height/2), m_scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
```

It is inefficient to have thousands of GPU calls like Draw().  It would be more efficient if you had a list of polygons in a buffer, where each polygon is located in the correct position and it has transparency information stored with it.  Then, with a SINGLE call to Draw(), you can then render all polygons with the correct texture and transparency.  Sorry I cannot provide you with code for this, but if you want to continue with your approach, this might be the direction you are headed.  In short, your GPU can certainly draw millions of polygons at a time, but it can't call Draw() that many times...

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, this is exactly the answer I was hoping for!

Comment: Those artifacts left by alpha blending, how would one go about preventing/avoiding that?

Comment: @Pondwater: 2 solutions I know: (1) Find out what is the final tone of those artifacts and make your original layer have that color.  Eg, if the artifacts have the color (5,5,5), instead of starting with a black screen (0,0,0), start with (5,5,5). Not perfect, but it works & it's easy. (2) You should be able to choose the type of alpha blending used during rendering.  The default is "multiplicative".  There should be one that is "additive" or "subtractive".  All you have to do is add (-1,-1,-1) every once in a while to the whole screen to make sure that the color eventually goes to (0,0,0).

Comment: @Pondwater:  Hopefully, the "subtractive" blending won't result in negative values for colors.  I'd imagine that XNA truncates numbers less than 0 to 0.  The reason for those artifacts is the "multiplicative" blending.  When you multiply two weighted integers together, and you round the result, it is possible to never converge at the desired value.  If the tone of the artifacts is 1 or 2 values away from the desired final value and the final tone is a GRAYSCALE value, I'd recommend option 1.  There's not much difference between a background of (0,0,0) and (1,1,1) or even (10,10,10)...