# XNA - Sprite Ghost Trail

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am currently trying to create an ghosting trail similar to the one given in [this gif](https://i.imgur.com/8mlc915.gif).

I have tried creating multiple instances of my `Player` object based on the previous frame sequentially (`ghostimage = player;` on the current frame, `ghostimage2 = afterimage; afterimage = player;` on the next frame, etc.), but to no avail.

I even tried using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919526/8420233), but localized (only encompassing the needed areas).  It didn't work.

Drawing new `Player` objects with transparency (multiplying `Color.White` by some `float` value between `0f` and `1f`) didn't work well either.

How do I create this effect?

Comment: I found a solution.  I set the ghosts' textures to the player's texture at a certain frame and just set their position to the player at said frame.

Comment: If you have found a solution to your question, please share it as an answer with code to help those who follow that have the same question.

Comment: @Strom apologies.  I will do it when I get the time.